# how to change double click behavior in vscode editor to increase selected text scope

Tags: visual-studio-code, textselection

vscode editor double-clicking on words goes from single word selection to all line instead of gradually expanding the selection scope from word to text including quotations to full line.
The bracket select extension does it properly with CTRL+ALT+A keybinding to get the right selection behavior using the "bracket-select.select-include" command.

Is there a way to assign the keybinding to double-clicking so its easy to use and not have to keep doing `CTRL+ALT+A` ?
I tried this in keybindings.json but didnt work

```
[{
    "key": "doubleClick",
    "command": "bracket-select.select-include",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"   
  }
]
```

Comment: For me double click selects word and triple click select full line

Comment: Yes double click selects word and triple cliks selects full line which is not what I would expect when I am trying to select strings including quotes for copy/past. I would expect the selection scope to gradually increase with triple/quadruple click . Right now the CTRL+ALT+A with bracket select extension is the closest thing but not as fast as triple click